# Sub query doesn't return the same number of rows

Tags: mysql

I'm learning MySQL.  I do not understand why these two queries return different results.

This returns 94696 results

```
select count(*) from salaries where salary > 100000;
```

This returns 254687 results

```
select count(*) from salaries where emp_no 
in (select emp_no from salaries where salary > 100000);
```

Surely these two queries are equivalent and should return the same number of rows. What have I missed?

Comment: There is no 'surely' here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing the contents of the table "Salaries", in the first query you are asking for the count of salary rows with a salary higher than 100000 (would be nice).

However, in the second one, you are asking for all the emp_no (I assume employee number) that have at least a salary over 100000. That means that if a given emp_no can have multiple salaries, then you would be counting all of them.

Here is a quick example of what I mean, consider the following salaries table:

| emp_no | salary |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 100001 |
| 123 | 99999 |

The first query will return only the first row, and that means that the count(*) will be 1.

However, the second query is searching in the table by emp_no. The inner query returns only one emp_no (the one of the first row), but now the exterior query is like this

```
select count(*) from salaries where emp_no in (123) --that's the result of the inner query
```

That would return a total of 2.

Comment: Thanks Manu. I can see my confusion now.  I was in the mindset that the outer query was more like `count(distinct(emp_no))` but I can see now that's not the case and it will be counting all duplicates of the inner query.  Thanks for taking the time to clear that up.

Answer (score 0):

The latter query will return a count of all salaries for emp_nos that have any salary above 100000.  So if emp_no 123 has rows with salary 99999 and salary 100000, it will be counted as 1 in the first query and 2 in the second query.